# How many tangents can a point in R3 have?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function with a 2-dimensional input $(x, y)$ and a 1 dimensional output $z$.

From what I understand, a point described by $($$x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0}$$)$ will have $2$ tangent lines whose slopes are given by:

1. $\dfrac{\partial{f(x_{0},y_{0})}}{\partial{x}}$
2. $\dfrac{\partial{f(x_{0},y_{0})}}{\partial{y}}$

are there any more tangent lines possible for the point $($$x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0}$$)$ ?

Comment: These are the tangents in coordinate direction, but you can have a derivative in any direction.

Comment: It sounds like you’re asking about the tangent plane to a point on a surface given by $f$. Being a plane, it can be described by two vectors, which you’ve chosen. Any other line on that surface through that point is tangent to the surface at that point.

Comment: @Derek Allums. Didn't think about it that way, thank you!